# how to calculate maximum granularity (or intervals) between dates in table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table with 3 columns like

```
NAME     DATE_TIME                 AMOUNT
T1       2012:10:01  12:15:00        200
T1       2012:10:01  12:30:00        300
T1       2012:10:02  01:00:00        400
T1       2012:10:02  01:15:00        500
T1       2012:10:03  04:00:00        600
T1       2012:10:03  05:00:00        700
T2       2013:12:31  22:30:00        3838
T2       2013:12:31  23:00:00        7272
T2       2013:12:31  23:30:00        891
T2       2013:12:31  23:45:00        288
```

In the table T1 value the maximum interval is 15 mins and for T2 the maximun intervals is 30 Mins ,the output would be

NAME  Granularity/max.interval
T1         15   (mins)
T2         30   (mins)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a full demo.

```
-- SQL needed
SELECT 
    NAME, Granularity, cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        NAME, Granularity, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            IF(@last_name IS NULL OR NAME != @last_name OR DATE(@last_dt) != DATE(DATE_TIME),
               0, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @last_dt, DATE_TIME))AS Granularity,
            @last_name:=NAME,
            @last_dt:=DATE_TIME
        FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT @last_dt:=NULL, @last_name:=NULL) v
    ) t
    WHERE t.Granularity > 0 
    GROUP BY NAME, Granularity
) tt
WHERE 
    (NAME, cnt) IN 
    (
        SELECT NAME, MAX(cnt) max_cnt
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                NAME, Granularity, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    *,
                    IF(@last_name IS NULL OR NAME != @last_name OR DATE(@last_dt) != DATE(DATE_TIME),
                       0, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @last_dt, DATE_TIME))AS Granularity,
                    @last_name:=NAME,
                    @last_dt:=DATE_TIME
                FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT @last_dt:=NULL, @last_name:=NULL) v
            ) t
            WHERE t.Granularity > 0 
            GROUP BY NAME, Granularity
        ) ttt
        GROUP BY NAME
    );
```

The following is a full demo using the data you provided.

SQL:

```
-- data
create table t1(NAME char(20),  DATE_TIME datetime, AMOUNT int);
insert into t1 values
('T1',       '2012:10:01  12:15:00',        200),
('T1',       '2012:10:01  12:30:00',        300),
('T1',       '2012:10:02  01:00:00',        400),
('T1',       '2012:10:02  01:15:00',        500),
('T1',       '2012:10:03  04:00:00',        600),
('T1',       '2012:10:03  05:00:00',        700),
('T2',       '2013:12:31  22:30:00',        3838),
('T2',       '2013:12:31  23:00:00',        7272),
('T2',       '2013:12:31  23:30:00',        891),
('T2',       '2013:12:31  23:45:00',        288);
SELECT * FROM t1;




-- SQL needed
SELECT 
    NAME, Granularity, cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        NAME, Granularity, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            IF(@last_name IS NULL OR NAME != @last_name OR DATE(@last_dt) != DATE(DATE_TIME),
               0, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @last_dt, DATE_TIME))AS Granularity,
            @last_name:=NAME,
            @last_dt:=DATE_TIME
        FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT @last_dt:=NULL, @last_name:=NULL) v
    ) t
    WHERE t.Granularity > 0 
    GROUP BY NAME, Granularity
) tt
WHERE 
    (NAME, cnt) IN 
    (
        SELECT NAME, MAX(cnt) max_cnt
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                NAME, Granularity, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    *,
                    IF(@last_name IS NULL OR NAME != @last_name OR DATE(@last_dt) != DATE(DATE_TIME),
                       0, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @last_dt, DATE_TIME))AS Granularity,
                    @last_name:=NAME,
                    @last_dt:=DATE_TIME
                FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT @last_dt:=NULL, @last_name:=NULL) v
            ) t
            WHERE t.Granularity > 0 
            GROUP BY NAME, Granularity
        ) ttt
        GROUP BY NAME
    );
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+------+---------------------+--------+
| NAME | DATE_TIME           | AMOUNT |
+------+---------------------+--------+
| T1   | 2012-10-01 12:15:00 |    200 |
| T1   | 2012-10-01 12:30:00 |    300 |
| T1   | 2012-10-02 01:00:00 |    400 |
| T1   | 2012-10-02 01:15:00 |    500 |
| T1   | 2012-10-03 04:00:00 |    600 |
| T1   | 2012-10-03 05:00:00 |    700 |
| T2   | 2013-12-31 22:30:00 |   3838 |
| T2   | 2013-12-31 23:00:00 |   7272 |
| T2   | 2013-12-31 23:30:00 |    891 |
| T2   | 2013-12-31 23:45:00 |    288 |
+------+---------------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    ...
+------+-------------+-----+
| NAME | Granularity | cnt |
+------+-------------+-----+
| T1   |          15 |   2 |
| T2   |          30 |   2 |
+------+-------------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but for T1 if the dates are changed then it shows the Max.difference I.e 1650 it should be 15 mins (as it occurs most of the times) ,but if the day is same then it is giving the correct answer i.e for T2

Comment: What do you expect for the interval for the following two rows: T1       2012:10:01  12:30:00        300
T1       2012:10:02  01:00:00        400?

Comment: throught the T1 the maximum granularity is 15 mins irrespective of their date changes , Expecting to consider only time .. thanks @dylan

Comment: @su919 Updated the post, as you want. For T1, the max is 60 minutes.

Comment: Is the interval 60 minutes for the following two? T1       2012:10:03  04:00:00        600
T1       2012:10:03  05:00:00        700

Comment: yes correct @dylan , but max occuring granularity is 15 mins (first 4 rows)

Comment: I don't understand... max(15, 15, 60) is expected to return 15?

Comment: yes @Dylan , because that 15 interval occurs maximum times for T1